# VSCode: Prevent file from opening in a new tab and instead focus to already opened tab in another pane

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two files open side by side like shown in the picture:

[image: Split panes].

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the function name `two` in the left pane, I want VSCode to switch focus to already opened file `second.py` in the right pane. Instead, VSCode opens file `second.py` in a new tab in the current left pane (in a place indicated by red rectangle). Now you have three tabs instead of two, and `first.py` is obscured from view.

How can I change this behavior so that VSCode focuses already opened tab, instead of opening a new, redundant tab?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps this wasn't available when the question was posted here but there's dedicated setting to do this now:

```
"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in VS Code on windows by doing the following:

- ctrl+p
- type settings.json
- open the one in your user folder
- At the root level of the JSON add:

```
"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
```

`"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false"` means when you click a file it stays open. This is an optional part of this solution but I think it makes for a better DX.

`"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"` means when you open a file it will focus the tab of that file if it is already open.

Comment: no settings.json results for my when typing it